# Java error Consuming WCF Service

Tags: c#, java, wcf, jax-ws

I'm started to develop a Web Service with WCF and created a WCF Service poject. I let all as it was and imported the service in netbeans as JAX WS service. All seems to be fine.

```
Service1 test= new Service1();
CompositeType ct=new CompositeType();
ct.setBoolValue(Boolean.TRUE);
ObjectFactory factory=new ObjectFactory();
ct.setStringValue(factory.createString("StringValue"));    
CompositeType result= test.getBasicHttpBindingIService1().getDataUsingDataContract(ct);
```

I can send the request. I can break in Visual studio and see the CompositeType object. But the object is not as it should be:

- The bool value is set as expected to `true`.
- The string value is still `null`.
- When i manipulate the string value in the WCF Service and give the change object back the string is set correct and i can read it in java.

Why can't i post the CompositeType to java but can consume it?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from just the detail you've provided.

Here is what I suggest:

- Enable tracing on the service side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer. To do this, follow the instructions at [this MSDN article on using the service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). Notice what's different between the first and second time.
- Turn on debug exceptions. This is done by turning in includeExceptionDetailInFaults, which [you can do by following the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2006/11/12/how-to-turn-on-debug-exceptions-with-wcf.aspx). Notice what's different between the first and second time.
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the wire traffic on both the client side and the service side.

Generally, once you do this, you should plenty of more info on what's going funky at the service side and can diagnose the issue pretty quickly. Try it, and please report back! :)

Comment: thanks for all the infos up to now! i will try it and report back soon as possible!

Comment: Okay i did so, my conclution up to now (problem still not found). I can't find a error in the svclog file. I tought i can see there the soap request of the java clinet but i only see that the method was requestet but not with which soap request, can i see this somehow? The includeExeptionDetaillnFaults doesn't changed the service behavoir and no new faiulres were raised. Last but not least the fiddler. First of all it seems to be a great tool but I can't see the java request in it. If I open the wsdl in browser I can see this in the fiddler. How can I monitor the soap document of the request?

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp i found this page but i don't get it :(. I tried to change the Webconifg of my Applikation like this. 
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.0:8888" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net> but i still cant see anything at fiddler

Answer (score 1):

I also lost 2 hours in this!

The problem is in java code :)

Instead of this

```
ct.setStringValue(factory.createString("StringValue"));
```

use this

```
ct.setStringValue(factory.createCompositeTypeStringValue("StringValue"));
```